# Finding Difference between two rows grouped by a date or between two pivoted columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, obiee

I have a set of values for two different dates in my OBIEE report:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
Option   Date     Value 
------|---------|-------
OPT1    Date 1    5     
OPT1    Date 2    2     
OPT2    Date 1    9     
OPT2    Date 2    1     
OPT3    Date 1    7     
OPT3    Date 2    13    
OPT4    Date 1    5     
OPT4    Date 2    6
```

I hope to get the difference of Values between each set of date, and present the data in the following format, grouped by option:

```
Option  Date               Diff
        Date 1   Date 2 
------|--------|--------|-------  
OPT1    5        2        3
OPT2    9        1        8
OPT3    7        13       -6
OPT4    5        6        -1
```

The Date portion can be handled using Pivot, however I am unable to find the difference between the now pivoted columns.

I believe if the difference between the two values be found for a set of date (as shown below) and then pivoted, it might do the trick but i can't find the difference for a set.

```
Option  Date      Value   Diff
-------|---------|-------|-------
OPT1    Date 1    5       null
OPT1    Date 2    2        3
OPT2    Date 1    9       null
OPT2    Date 2    1        8
OPT3    Date 1    7       null
OPT3    Date 2    13       -6
OPT4    Date 1    5       null 
OPT4    Date 2    6       -1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Junaid

Comment: Please edit your question to include the query you used to pivot the data.

Comment: Also, how do you know which Date 1 rows are linked to Date 2 rows? There's column to link them.

Comment: @JunaidAhmad . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies the ordering.  And you don't seem to have such a column.

Comment: I have edited my question. Added a column to link the dates. Helpful?

Comment: Just to add my 10 cents - that's not how OBIEE is built nor how it works. OBI uses *models*. You're not writing SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to, and do calculations using, the columns generated by the pivot clause. Assuming you have some key value linking the pairs of values for dates 1 and 2, you can do something like:

```
-- CTE for sample data, with made-up keys
with your_table (some_key, some_date, value) as (
            select 1, date '2019-04-01', 5 from dual
  union all select 1, date '2019-04-15', 2 from dual
  union all select 2, date '2019-04-01', 9 from dual
  union all select 2, date '2019-04-15', 1 from dual
  union all select 3, date '2019-04-01', 7 from dual
  union all select 3, date '2019-04-15', 13 from dual
  union all select 4, date '2019-04-01', 5 from dual
  union all select 4, date '2019-04-15', 6 from dual
)
-- actual query
select some_key, date1, date2, date1 - date2 as diff
from your_table
pivot (max(value) for some_date in (date '2019-04-01' as date1, date '2019-04-15' as date2))
order by some_key;

  SOME_KEY      DATE1      DATE2       DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          5          2          3
         2          9          1          8
         3          7         13         -6
         4          5          6         -1
```

In the `date1 - date2 as diff` expression, `date1` and `date2` are the names/aliases from the pivot. You can't usually use a column alias in the same level of query that defines it, but pivot lets you get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think i got the solution for doing the row-wise subtraction partitioned by option

VALUE - LAG(VALUE, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY OPTION ORDER BY OPTION)

However, due to certain restrictions, I am unable to use DB functions in OBIEE. I would like to learn of a solution which doesn't involve using DB functions (like LAG/LEAD).